# Mapping only first letter of file C

Tags: c, file, dictionary, winapi, mapping

how can I map only the first letter of my file??
I've tried these value for parameters :

```
1, // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
1, // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
```

(i don't know the difference between them).

is 1 the right parameter for an only 1 letter mapping?

```
#define FILENAME "c:\gibrish.bin" 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  HANDLE hFile;
  LPCSTR pFileName = FILENAME;
  hFile = CreateFileA(pFileName, // file name 
                      FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // access type 
                      0, // other processes can't share
                      NULL, // security
                      OPEN_EXISTING, // open only if file exists
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  HANDLE hMapFile;

  ////////mapping here
  hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(hFile, // file handle
                                NULL, // default security
                                FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read access 
                                1, // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
                                1, // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                                   // 0 means map the whole file 
                                "gibrishFile"); // name of mapping object, in case we 
                                                // want to share it


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First line already has a problem: `"c:\gibrish.bin"` should be `"c:\\gibrish.bin"`. And you don't do any error checking.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok thanks, but can you please answer the question?

Comment: If the section is backed by an ordinary file, *MaximumSize* specifies the maximum size that the file can be extended or mapped to. if you set it to value less to current file size - it have no effect. and view of section always roundsmultiple of `PAGE_SIZE`. you can not map 1 byte. map of view will be how minimum `PAGE_SIZE` (4096 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I map only the first letter of my file??
> I've tried these value for parameters :
>
> ```
> 1, // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
> 1, // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
> ```

these two parameters makes (a huge) number, if the number you want to give is 1 or any other under 2^32 the `high-order DWORD` must be 0. If you give 1 and 1 this means the number is 1*(2^32) + 1 = 4294967296, this is not compatible with only the first letter

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types :

> DWORD A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.

Comment: so, in order to get only the first letter, should I write it like that?   0, // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
1, // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)

Comment: @Mayuu yes this is that

Comment: @Mayuu in addition to this answer: add error checks in your code, `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileMappingA` can fail. You need to check the return value of theses function. Read the docs carefully. `CreateFileA` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` upon failure and `CreateFileMappingA` returns `NULL` upon failure. `GetLastError()` returns the error code. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for your advice. I added error checks, and found out that CreateFileA returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE  as you said.  What can be the reason for that?

Comment: @Mayuu - read first comment under your post. and call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` and/or `GetLastError()` if you want know reason

Comment: @Mayuu You may not have enough authority to visit the folder you are using("C:\\").

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameters `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` in `CreateFileMappingA` [msdn doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga). The return value will always be failed, with `GetLastError()` return 87(`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`). And the folder you are accessing is the "`C:\\`", If you don't have enough authority, `CreateFileA` will return a `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and get error of 5(`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`).

`CreateFileMappingA` is used for creating space for mapping, but not the actual size you want to map. And then use `MapViewOfFile()` mapping into the address space of a calling process. And the size you want to map must <= the size you create.